# I'd like to know if I used 'when it comes to~' right here

Tags: sentence-construction

> I'm a person who doesn't like to do something new. And ***even when it comes to foods***, I don't like to eat something that I haven't eaten before.

I'd like to know if I used 'when it comes to~' right here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idiom "when it comes to something" is used to convey the sense of as for/as regards something or when it's a question of something.

The OP has correctly used the idiom in his sentence.